# Define physicsBody of a SKSpriteNode in a separate SKSpriteNode subclass - Swift2

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I have a class called Bird, that is a SKSpriteNode. I do have it initialized, but I can't figure out how to set physicsBody and other properties of it in that same class rather than in GameScene class.

Bird class:

```
import SpriteKit

class Bird: SKSpriteNode {

    init() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "birdy")
        let size = texture.size()

        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(size.width/4, size.height/4))
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
```

A function for setting the properties of Bird in GameScene:

```
var birdSprite: Bird!

func setupBird() {
    birdSprite = Bird()
    birdSprite.position = CGPointMake(size.width*0.5, size.height*0.2)
    birdSprite.zPosition = Layer.Bird.rawValue
    self.addChild(birdSprite)

    birdSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: birdSprite.size.width/2)
    birdSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bird
    birdSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    birdSprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Desk
    birdSprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    birdSprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    birdSprite.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
}
```

I tried setting its physics body by defining it in Bird class, with self.physicsBody = ..., but that gave me an error, as well as setting it the same way inside the init function, so I didn't include it here in the code.

The reason I want to do it in a separate class is that I would like to learn how to write well organized code, so that the code would be more readable and self explanatory. But I am more or less a beginner at Swift and programming in general, so the lack of experience and knowledge is giving me some troubles.

Any help or suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to set these properties after the call to `super.init()`?

Since the properties you want to set are from the superclass, these can only be setted after this call, like in:

```
init() {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "birdy")
    let size = texture.size()

    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(size.width/4, size.height/4))

    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width/2)
}
```

I don't know exactly what did you do first in the `init()`, but maybe this is the case.

Comment: It works! As you have suggested, it wasn't working because I was setting it before the initialization, thank you!